# What is difference between `pyspark.sql.SparkSession.sql` and `SQLContext.read.format()`?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to fire a query to database using spark. For now I'm using the method

```
df = SQLContext.read.format('jdbc')
               .option('url',database_url)
               .option('dbtable',my_query)
               .option('numpartitions',number_of_partitions)
               .option(...)
```

which is working perfectly fine. But there's another method to fire the query in pyspark called

```
df = pyspark.sql.SparkSession().sql(myquery)
```

Both are returning dataframes.

So few question regarding this :

1) What exactly is the difference between these two ?

2) In case of `pyspark.sql.SparkSession().sql(myquery)` , how to set all the parameters like database URL, number of partitions etc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Until Spark 1.6, Spark had many contexts such as `sqlcontext`, `hivecontext`, etc., to work with different types of data sources. With Spark2, the starting point of the Spark applications comes with `SparkSession` which subsumes all the said contexts.
2. `DataFrameReader` offers support for that using `jdbc` API. You can execute the following to achieve what you want:

   `df = spark.read.jdbc(url, table, numPartitions=number_of_partitions)`

Even this one should work:

```
df = spark.read.format('jdbc').option('url',database_url)
                              .option('dbtable',my_query)
                              .option('numpartitions',number_of_partitions)
                              .option()......
```

`spark` refered in the above snippets are nothing but `SparkSession`. Take a look at the relevant API [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc)

Comment: that's helpful ! thanks ! one more question is does SQLContext supports hive ? i'm using spark 2.3.0

Comment: Like I said, `SparkContext`, `SQLContext`, `HiveContext` are focused for Spark 1.x. These contexts exist in Spark2 purely for backward compatibility. Since you're using Spark2, just use `SparkSession` which comes with all the contexts already included.

Comment: And for reference on how to access Hive table using `SparkSession`: Get a SparkSession by calling `spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport.getOrCreate()` Then use `spark.sql()` to query and access Hive tables